# Display data in lwc datatable as pdf

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, visualforce, lwc

I want to display data as pdf that is in my lightning datatable in lwc. These list i am getting from api response . It can range from 10 to 2000 or even more.
So I tried below method to pass data to VF page
Approach 1 :
Passing list as string parameter to VF page URL , but that is hitting my URL limit.
Approach 2:
Declared get set variable in lwc controller and assigning values on click on print button, but that print blank pdf page .

Approach1:
LWC apex controller

```
Pagereference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Locations');
pageRef.getParameters().put('locations',locWrapList);
pageRef.getParameters().put('brandName',brandName);
```

It is giving URL limit error
Approach 2:

```
lisOfLocation= (List<LocationWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(locWrapList, List<LocationWrapper>.class);
```

I am using this lisOfLocation in VF page ,  but on click of print it is printing blank

Is there any way I can handle this.